# Vision bluriness

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics, vision

I don’t know much about vision so I hope one of you guys could clarify me…

When people who have vision problems look at an object without their glasses, they’ll see this object with a certain level of blurriness right?

Now if I take someone who has a perfect vision, I tell him to watch an image displayed on a screen that was purposely blurred, could this person see the original and sharp image if he would use glasses with a certain strength? I know the image would have to be blurred in a special way but still…would it be possible?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the blurring is intrinsic to the image (i.e. it's displayed on a computer screen and the blurring was done by software, or, say, that it's a photograph of an object through an imperfectly-focused lens), then **no**, no amount of optical correction will bring the original image back into focus. The information about that original image is lost, and simply cannot be recovered.

When we see blurry images because of imperfect vision, it means that point sources in the object are not focused into point images in our retina, producing instead a blur with multiple points receiving light, but the information is still present, as each of those points will be hit by light coming from a different direction. That's what allows optical correction to work.

In your scheme, this is no longer the case, so optical correction won't work. The image is already at its optimal sharpness, and adding optical correction either way will just make the image blurrier (or, more realistically, it will force the eye's lens to do more effort to keep it at its minimal, nonzero blurriness).